# Show Feed with PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

I want to ask, I see script this thread.

Script is still working fine but I want to include many feed and bring up on my website, how can I solve it?

```
example:
web1.domain.com/feed
web2.domain.com/feed
web3.domain.com/feed
...
```

I want to show feed subdomain to my top level domain.

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://web.domain.com/feed/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $htmlStr = $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $html = new DOMDocument();        
    $html->loadHTML($htmlStr);
    //get the first image tag from the description HTML
        $imgTag = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $img = ($imgTag->length==0)?'noimg.png':$imgTag->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
        $item = array (
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'category' => $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'image' => $img,
            );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 2;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $img = $feed[$x]['image'];
    $category = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['category']);
    $date = date('j F Y G:i', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">';
    echo '<div class="blog-widget-img left relative">';
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'" height="100" width="165">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="blog-widget-text left relative">';
    echo '<span class="side-list-cat">'.$category.'</span>';
    echo '<h2>'.$title.'</h2>';
    echo '<span><time>'.$date.'</time></span>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
I have found the solution check and it works

```
$my_feeds = array('http://web1.domain.com/feed', 
                    'http://web2.domain.com/feed',
                    'http://web3.domain.com/feed');
foreach ($my_feeds as $my_feed)
{
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load ($my_feed); //load more feed with variable
    $feed = array();
    //star feed here
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/jewelhuq/Online-News-Grabber check out this one. it might help you

Comment: @jewelhuq I no understand, I use CMS Woordpress and I want to show artikel subdomain in top level domain because if I post artikel in subdomain I post too in top level domain, so I post twice.